# Using android dungeons example how can I Retrieve Order Number from inapp purchase

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I currently am using the dungeons example to implement inApp purchase from google and for the most part seems to be working. I currently load the purchases into my database to store all purchases made by a given user the is is stored by a udid I get from the device this is done when I see the onPurchaseStateChange method returns PurchaseState.PURCHASED. I need to be able to map this to one of the following pieces of data either the Google order number our the company Order Number
exampled by this which is shown on the receipt that is sent to the customer.

```
Google order number: 4444555552219333 - XYZ Inc Order #66666633355555224444.3332214444224444
```

How can I do this. I can't find where this information is returned from google during the transaction.
Hopefully when I find out that the PurchaseState.PURCHASED is returned I also have the ability to get additional data that matched either of the order numbers with the same call but if I have to make another one  I guess I could make the call at this point but I do not know when to make it or what to actually call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found while continuing to research for an answer:

When a user purchases an in-app item, Google Checkout assigns the transaction a unique and permanent order number. Google Play provides that order number to you at the conclusion of the purchase flow, as the value of the orderId field of the PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED intent.

In your app, you can use the order number as a general-purpose identifier for the in-app purchase transaction. After the purchase, you can use the order number as a means of tracking the transaction in reconciliation reports and for customer support.

The order number itself is a string consisting of numbers only, with a format assigned and managed by Google Checkout.

For transactions dated 5 December 2012 or later, Google Checkout assigns a Merchant Order Number (rather than a Google Order Number) and reports the Merchant Order Number as the value of orderID. Here's an example:

"orderId" : "12999556515565155651.5565135565155651"

For transactions dated previous to 5 December 2012, Google checkout assigned a Google Order Number and reported that number as the value of orderID. Here's an example of an orderID holding a Google Order Number:

"orderId" : "556515565155651"

So by parsing the intent you can determine the specific order it is associated with and store it or use it to confirm purchases or other details